# Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition Solution File

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I created a new ASP.NET website using Visual Web Developer 2008 Express edition and am not able to find the solution file. Does Visual Web Developer 2008 Express edition generate a solution file when we create a new ASP.NET website ?

How can I open multiple websites within the same IDE window?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is to not display the solution file if there's only one project in it. Use Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions, then check the "Always show solution" button.

If you're going to have multiple projects of any kind, you may want to create a blank solution in a directory above where you'll put the project directories. Use File->New Project, "Other Project Types", "Blank Visual Studio Solution".